# CSS best practices for fields with different widths

Tags: html, css

I was discussing with my boss about removing all styles from our HTML pages, but we found a little problem. In our form fields have different widths and I want to do the things right. What is the "correct way" / best practices to accomplish this?

We have a css class "textField"

```
.textField {
   background-color: White;
   border: 1px solid gray;
   color: Black;
   font-family: Tahoma;
   font-size: 11px;
   font-weight: bold;
   text-align: left;
}
```

So we should stay with the `style='width:100px'` at the html pages?

We should create another classes just with the widths and use together?

Ex.:

```
size100 { 
   width: 100px
} 

size200 { 
   width: 200px
}
```

and use `class="textField size100"`? I know the name `size100` isn't a good practice, and if this is a good way, what name should I use instead?

Is there a better way?

Comment: The correct way would be to add width: 100px; to the element itself. By creating loads of "utility/helper classes" all you are really doing is just cluttering your html, just not with styles but class names

Comment: Is it the only text field of it's kind, or are there variations in the widths across multiple text fields? Or are the styles particular to a certain form?

Comment: This is less a discussion of "best practices" and more of a personal preference for design policy. I have found a less is more approach to work best. You would do best by working out your design policy. Decide what is important to how your page is displayed, what is necessary. As long as you keep your CSS organized and consistent, you shouldn't have problems with clutter.

Comment: I know you're asking about CSS, but there is also a JS/jQuery solution if your purpose is to set all labels in a particular container to the same width...you could eliminate the css altogether with a single line of jquery code `$('#containingDIV span,#containingDIV label').width(100);`  Alternatively, there is an autowidth.js file floating around the internet that will auto adjust  width's with the widest label in the container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to use non-presentational class names like these:

```
text-medium
text-small
text-large
```

And then put the rules like this:

```
.text-medium {width: 200px;}
```

The main reasons are:

1. It is understandable.
2. It doesn't depend on size.
3. If we need to change the size or make it responsive, you just need to change the value in the CSS rather than the rule name! :)

Comment: Thanks, it'll help me a lot

Answer (score 1):

another way is using a grid system in your form, like used in bootstrap framework:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-sizes

check the link above, he uses class with different column sizes, you can use it in all your form.

```
<input class="form-control input-lg" type="text" placeholder=".input-lg">
```

where, input-lg = large, input-sm = small.

Answer (score 0):

I would use multiple classes like you mentioned. class="textField small", class="textField medium", ...

```
.textField {
    background-color: White;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    color: Black;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
 }

 .textField.small {
     width:100px;
 }

 .textField.medium {
     width:200px;
 }
```

This way you write the input styles once and only change what is needed. If you want to change the border (or color, background, etc) in the future you can change it in one spot without updating a bunch of different classes